# Global optimization of polynomial in several variables in Maple?

Tags: maple

I cannot find a suitable command for global optimization of a polynomial in 6 variables in Maple. Anyone know of any free package or commands?

Ive tried NLPSOLVE with variuos setting but this give only a local minima I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLPSolve will only find local extrema.

There's a free third-party package called DirectSearch that you can download from the Maple Applications Center. It has a command GlobalOptima. The package has a vast number of options and input formats (but, thankfully, only one output format), so let me know if you need further assistance.